# Windows Application Profilers - C++ Exe

Tags: c++, unit-testing, profiling, profiler

I have a bat script which calls out to an exe and starts this off - I dont know what language it is written in (Probably C++)

I want to find a profiler that allows me to run a command a few times and gathers IO/CPU and other stats

It needs to be open source where possible

Any suggestions

Comment: You can collect good cpu/IO usage stats on Windows Vista and above using Perfmon. Its also there on XP but not as good.

Comment: You won't find one.  Profilers require special information to be within or about the executable.  This requires special, implementation defined switches during compilation.  People don't generally release products compiled this way.  They run slow as hell for one thing.  Unless you can recompile the program, and it sounds like you don't even know what the source looks like, you can't profile it.  Provided this info as comment so you can hopefully delete the question before it's negged into oblivion.

Comment: I/O and CPU stats should definitely be available via performance counters.  As @Noah says, the type of call tree correlation normally associated with profiling would require debug data, but since it doesn't seem like you care about that, the situation is nowhere near as grim as he says.

Comment: @Noah - Profilers don't necessarily need debug builds. (In fact I'd argue that profiling a debug build is somewhat beside the point.) Sure you need debug information (pdb files on VC++) to display meaningful results, but a release build really should be sufficient. (And *is* sufficient with one tool we work with: http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/)

Answer (score 1):

You may try Performance Analysis of Logs (PAL) - http://pal.codeplex.com
It has predefined templates for major system metrics (see System Overview template).

It may automatically create quite impressive report including graphs and brief explanations on detected 'hotspots'.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Glowcode (www.glowcode.com) in the past. It's not open source, but quite easy to use, can profile an executable, and is available on an evaluation basis as well.

I recall it was quite cheap as well.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, XPERF is your friend, and is a free download.

Check out the [Windows Performace Analysis Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc825801) site for more information on this and other tools.

Have fun!